How do Wild Cards affect the Flower Pot joker?
The description for the Flower Pot joker says:

X3 Mult if poker hand contains a Diamond card, Club card, Heart card, and Spade card

How are Wild Cards treated when calculating the Flower Pot bonus? Is one wild Card enough to get the bonus? If not, would one heart and three wild cards trigger it?


Wiki on Flower Pot and Modifiers says Wild Cards Good.

A Wild Card can count as any suit, but only one; i.e. a single Wild Card will not earn the entire bonus by itself. However, four Wild Cards, or three Wild Cards and a normal suited card, will always earn the bonus.

